# Lisp - Finding the max depth in a list of nested lists

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp

So I am writing a grammar in Lisp and want to find the maximum depth of the tree for the grammar.

For example,

```
(SENTENCE (NOUN-PHRASE (DETERMINER THE) (NOUNPLURAL MEN))
 (VERB-PHRASE-PAST 
  ((VERBPAST SAW) (NOUN-PHRASE (DETERMINER THE) (NOUNPLURAL DOGS)))))
```

The maximum depth should be 4 (Sentence -> verb-phrase-past -> noun-phrase -> determiner -> the).
The list-length however is 3, and will always be incorrect when the interior lists are expanded.

How can I write a function to return this max depth (without using any external libraries)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(defun max-depth (tree)
  (if (atom tree)
      0
      (1+ (reduce #'max (mapcar #'max-depth tree)))))
```

You may need to change the 0 value to suit your specifications.

Note: edited to use `REDUCE` instead of `APPLY`. `REDUCE` does not have any list length limits.

Comment: use REDUCE instead of APPLY for list operations.

Comment: @RainerJoswig, how is `reduce` better than `apply`? `max` reduces its arguments anyway.

Comment: @Mark: this code above is only portably working with lists up to 50 items. See the variable `CALL-ARGUMENTS-LIMIT` in Common Lisp. GCL: 64, LispWorks: 2047, CLISP 4096... `REDUCE` does not have this limit. `REDUCE` is for folding arbitrary sequences (lists and vectors). `APPLY` is for applying functions to *argument lists* - which can have a size limit as low as 50 arguments.

Comment: @RainerJoswig do you mind posting the better answer as a comment to make it clear and easy for these finding this question?

Comment: @William: I've changed this answer instead.

Comment: @RainerJoswig side question what editor are you using to keep all the lines and spacing appropriate?